# Filepicker gem for Rails - how can I set up my own Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, ruby, filepicker, filepicker.io

I am trying to extend the basic functionality of this gem. The basic functionality works well.
What I am trying to do:

```
:javascript
  var filepicker = filepicker.setKey('my key');
  function check_mimetype(file_data){
    filepicker.get_file('image/*', function(file_data.url, file_data.mimytype){ #error pointing here
    ...
  });

  }
```

But I always get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I don't know what can be wrong - Filepicker's key is added, Filepicker's JS library is loaded... 
This data are in the file **_form.html.haml**.
(jQuery is obviously loaded as well)

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function with argument names that have a `.` in them.  That's not allowed.  Try:

```
filepicker.get_file('image/*', function(file_url, file_mimetype) {
...
```